# Quotient of $W^V$ modulo $\hom(V, W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

For vector space $V, W$, all mappings $V\to W$ is a vector space $W^V$, all linear mappings $\hom(V, W)$ is a subspace of $W^V$. So it's natural to think about the quotient space $W^V/\hom(V,W)$. I am wondering if there is practical usage of such a quotient space?